# Ruby on rails/LDAP - Create a list of all user in a LDAP

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ldap

i try to create a list of all users present in a LDAP. A directory if you prefer. I want to take all informations in the ldap (name, mail, mobile phone, avatar...)

I can connect on the website with Devise_ldap_authenticable, that's my code :

ldap.yml :

```
development:
    host: ldap.**.com
    port: 652
    attribute: uid
    base: ou=2013,ou=people,dc=**,dc=com
    # admin_user: cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
    # admin_password: admin_password
    ssl: false
    # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

My user models :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :ldap_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable
end
```

I can connect okay, but now i want to create a simple page with the list of all person present in the LDAP.

How can i do that, i've no idea. thx for you help :) !